# small question about cloudflair

Tags: ip

Some friend advice me to install ( CloudFlair )  on my server

to get high security ...

i have small question

is CloudFlair allow me to change my server ip adress to fake one?

for example:

my server real ip is: 133.33.33.33

can i change it with new fake one for attackers?

if any one make ping for my site .. he see the fake ip .. 22.22.22.22 <- fake ip

is that possible?

thank you

Comment: Contact CloudFlair sales:  https://www.cloudflare.com/contact.html

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question, no, because the IP must be routable to your server. And you can't just pick another IP address, since if it's an actual routable address then someone else owns it.

What would be the point in changing your IP? It would be like hiding your street address to keep away burglars. Your IP address, if it's a public address, is out there and known (or discoverable). Your security relies on making sure your server is up to date with a minimum attack surface, your bandwidth can handle the traffic it'll get, and your server is running intrusion detection measures and has a good backup (and disaster recovery plan) in place.